# How to merge 3 images(100x100px) to one new large (300x100px) in Swift

Tags: image, swiftui, uiimage

iam very new to swiftUI and dont found a way.

I want to create one image (300x100) dyncmicaly by merging three single 100x100 images horizontaly

ImageA(100x100) + ImageB(100x100) + ImageC(100x100) = ImageD(300x100)

Found a way to show them in a HStack but how can is get one new image to send the Date to new function

Regards
Alex

Comment: FWIW, while you can combine them into a single image, as shown below, I'd personally be inclined stick with the `HStack`. If you combine the three into a single image, you're then taking up more memory, requiring the memory for each of the three separate images as well as memory for the new combined image. Plus with the `HStack` you can more easily control spacing, alignment, etc. But both approaches work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIImageGraphicsRenderer` and `draw` the images one after another:

```
func combineHorizontally(_ images: [UIImage]) -> UIImage? {
    guard !images.isEmpty else { return nil }

    var size = CGSize.zero
    var scale = CGFloat.zero

    for image in images {
        scale = max(scale, image.scale)
        size = CGSize(width: size.width + image.size.width, height: max(size.height, image.size.height))
    }

    var position = CGPoint.zero
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    format.scale = scale

    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { _ in
        for image in images {
            image.draw(at: position)
            position.x += image.size.width
        }
    }
}
```

You said that there were only images and they were 100 × 100, but the above should work regardless of the number and size (memory permitting, of course).

Anyway, this

```
let image = combineHorizontally([redImage, greenImage, blueImage])
```

Results in:

[image]

---

To use that in a context where you don’t want an optional, you can use `!` forced unwrapping operator, `??` nil coalescing operator, or some other unwrapping pattern, e.g. `guard let`, `if let`, etc.

Alternatively, if you don’t want to deal with optionals at all, you can write a rendition that doesn’t return an optional at all (but also doesn’t detect the error scenario where an empty array was provided):

```
func combineHorizontally(_ images: [UIImage]) -> UIImage {
    var size = CGSize.zero
    var scale: CGFloat = 1
    
    for image in images {
        scale = max(scale, image.scale)
        size = CGSize(width: size.width + image.size.width, height: max(size.height, image.size.height))
    }
    
    var position = CGPoint.zero
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    format.scale = scale
    
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { _ in
        for image in images {
            image.draw(at: position)
            position.x += image.size.width
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Rob, thanks a lot, I tried to use your function but got an error here "Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected element type 'UIImage'!

Comment: @BigAL82 - You have to unwrap the optional (e.g. use `!` forced unwrapping operator, `??` nil coalescing operator, or some other unwrapping pattern, e.g. `guard let`, `if let`, etc.).

Comment: @BigAL82 - See revised answer above for a rendition that doesn’t return optional.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, I tried to use your function but got an error here "Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected element type 'UIImage'!

Code should drat 3x zero. in the number-0.png ist just one lagre zero

```
    //
//  ContentView.swift
//  imagecombine
//
//  Created by Alex on 02.08.20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Alex. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

func combineHorizontally(_ images: [UIImage]) -> UIImage? {
    guard !images.isEmpty else { return nil }

    var size = CGSize.zero
    var scale = CGFloat.zero

    for image in images {
        scale = max(scale, image.scale)
        size = CGSize(width: size.width + image.size.width, height: max(size.height, image.size.height))
    }

    var position = CGPoint.zero
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    format.scale = scale

    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format).image { context in
        for image in images {
            image.draw(at: position)
            position.x += image.size.width
        }
    }
}
let redImage = UIImage(named: "number-0.png")
let greenImage = UIImage(named: "number-0.png")
let blueImage = UIImage(named: "number-0.png")

let image = combineHorizontally([redImage, greenImage, blueImage])

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        
         Image(image)
        
        
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

Comment: not a big deal, but the code you’ve copied here is licensed as [cc by-sa](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing). You shouldn’t be adding your own personal copyright to it. (I know this copyright text was probably just added by Xcode, but nonetheless, proper attribution is required.)